# Take NSMutableString and convert to CSV file for email

Tags: uitableview, swift2, xcode7, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to take my data from a `UITableView` which is `var toDoItems:[String] = []`. I'm trying to take this data and convert it to a CSV file for emailing. I cannot find any current information on this with Xcode 7 and Swift 2.  Everything I've found is Objective C.  I'm new to programming so trying to convert Objective C to Swift 2 is hard for me. I talked to a buddy of mine who said to take my `UITableView` data and convert it to an `NSMutableString`.  Then convert my `NSMutableString` to `NSData`.  He said the `NSData` could be written to a CSV file.

One section of code is:

```
// Helps to have it APPEAR when adding new items **
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Checks to see if there are any past items to boot up with
    if let storedtoDoItems : AnyObject = savedDefaults.objectForKey("toDoItems") {

        //If there are, it sets the array to nothing
        toDoItems = []

        for var i = 0; i < storedtoDoItems.count; ++i {
            toDoItems.append(storedtoDoItems[i] as! String)

            // Convert stored tableView data to string
            incomingString = String(toDoItems)
        }
    }
    tasksTable.reloadData()
}
```

I have the following variables declared:

```
var toDoItems:[String] = []
var convertString: NSString!
var convertMutable: NSMutableString!
var incomingString: String = ""
var datastring: NSString!
```

Here is my export button action:

```
// PDF Button
@IBAction func pdfExport(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Convert tableView String Data to NSMutableString if needed
    convertMutable = NSMutableString(UTF8String: incomingString)
    print("NSMutableString: \(convertMutable)")

    // Convert tableView String Data to NSString if needed
    convertString = String(incomingString)
    print("NSString: \(convertString)")

    // Convert above NSString to NSData
    let data = convertString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    if let d = data { // Unwrap since data is optional and print
        print("NSData: \(d)")
    }
    // Convert NSData back to NSString to verify NSData was actual data and test
    datastring = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
    print("Back to NSString: \(datastring)")

}
```

Can someone please help me with examples of how to do this with Swift 2?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did some research and figured it out.

The code for the `@IBAction func` I put:

```
// CSV Export Button
@IBAction func csvExport(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Convert tableView String Data to NSMutableString
    convertMutable = NSMutableString();
    for item in toDoItems
    {
        convertMutable.appendFormat("%@\r", item)
    }

    print("NSMutableString: \(convertMutable)")

    // Convert above NSMutableString to NSData
    let data = convertMutable.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    if let d = data { // Unwrap since data is optional and print
        print("NSData: \(d)")
    }

    //Email Functions
    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("CSV File Export")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
        mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "TodoList.csv")

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    // Compose Email
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert() // One of the MAIL functions
    }
}
```

I also added these two functions for the email:

```
// Mail alert if user does not have email setup on device
func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}
// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

It worked great and created the CSV file and attached it in an email, opening the Mail App ready for the 'To' address.  This is for Swift 2 and Xcode 7.